# Multiline label in collection view cell breaks after reuse

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uicollectionviewcell

I have a custom UICollectionViewCell with several UI elements, laid out using AutoLayout setup in code.

On larger devices (iPhone 6 and up) everything works as expected.

On smaller devices however, a multiline UILabel breaks, but only (it seems) after reuse.

On initial display, the first cell looks like this:

[image: Initial display of cell]

After the cell has been scrolled off screen and brought back on again, it looks like this:

[image: Second display of cell]

These are the constraints set up on the label:

```
    descriptionLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: firstButton.centerXAnchor),
    descriptionLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: otherLabel.leadingAnchor),
    descriptionLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: firstButton.bottomAnchor, constant: 15),
    secondButton.topAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: descriptionLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 20),
```

I feel like it's something to do with the `greaterThanOrEqualTo` constraint, but if I replace that with a plain old `equalTo` constraint, the layout goes wild and the label shrinks down to only fit one line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've faced the similar problem in `UICollectionView` and I found solution in `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` property and `widthAnchor`

```
productNameLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.6)
productNameLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.frame.size.width * 0.6
```

it should fix the problem.

Comment: The `leading` and `centreX` should take care of the width, but I'll take a look in to the `preferredMaxLayoutWidth`.

Comment: I'm not sure about that `leading` and `centerX` should care about the width. This means pin label to left or right and center me in X axis. So if I understand constraints correctly it might produce some conflicts. I suggest to use `leading` and set the `width`

Comment: However I had the same problem in my `UICollectionViewCells` while reusing and this fix the problem :)

Comment: `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` seems to have fixed my problem - thanks!
I can confirm though that `leading` and `centreX` works for horizontal position and width. The leading constraint gives the view it's x position, and the view knows it needs to line it's middle up with the middle of another view, so adjusts it's width accordingly (Y)